# How do I set background color in libgdx?

Tags: java, colors, libgdx

I am trying to make the background a sky blue color with RGB of 135,206,235.
When I run it, the background is not the color I expected.

```java
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.135f, .206f, .235f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: use `135/255f` instead of `.125f` (and same for other 2 channels)

Answer (score 20):

`glClearColor` uses range from 0 to 1, so you need to map from range 0 - 255 by simply dividing by constant 255f:

```java
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(135/255f, 206/255f, 235/255f, 1);
```

Also be cautious when dividing 2 integers, if you don't convert any of then to float (or double), integer division will be used and result will be 0 (except for 255/255 == 1)